# AVCaptureSession restart recording performance optimization

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, performance, video

I have following code which performs stop running (video) session, delete last segment of video, store video to directory and starts new video recording. There is (naturally) gap between these two video segments. Is there any way to optimize this code (maybe assync optimization if possible)? By optimization I mean elimination time gap as much as possible between these two video segments, thank you.

```
- (void) restartVideoRecording {

        [captureSession removeOutput:captureMovieOutput];
        [captureMovieOutput stopRecording];

        if(lastPathWasOne){
            captureMoviePath = [[URLPathProvider getUrlPathProvider]videoTwoPathString];
            [URLPathProvider deleteFileAtStringPath:captureMoviePath];
            lastPathWasOne = NO;
        } else {
            captureMoviePath = [[URLPathProvider getUrlPathProvider]videoOnePathString];
            [URLPathProvider deleteFileAtStringPath:captureMoviePath];
            lastPathWasOne = YES;
        }
        captureMovieURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:captureMoviePath];
        [captureSession addOutput:captureMovieOutput];
        [captureMovieOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:captureMovieURL recordingDelegate:self];
    }
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:loopDuration target:self selector:@selector(restartVideoRecording) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Store captured samples in NSTemporaryDirectory and use AVMutableComposition to merge assets at the end of recording session.

there is a [Sample code](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iPhone-Pause.html) please check this also

Comment: Thank you for link. I have been looking for such a fantastic code for a weeks!